# How To Pass The JQuery UI Sliders' Current Value into Code Behind in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

this is my javascript code

```
        $(document).ready(function () {

            var txtStart = $("#TextBox1");
            var txtStartDate = $(txtStart).val(); //Value from arrival

            var txtEnd = $("#TextBox2");
            var txtEndDate = $(txtEnd).val();
            var minDate = new Date(txtStartDate);
            var maxDate = new Date(txtEndDate);
```

here i have create a slider

```
            $("#slider").slider({
                min: minDate.getTime(),
                max: maxDate.getTime(),
                step: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000, // 1 day

                slide: function (e, ui) {
                    var currentDate = new Date(ui.value);
                    $('#now').text(currentDate.toDateString());
              },
```

i wand to pass the ui value into aspx.cs once the slider value change

```
                change: function (e, ui) { //get the ui value into code behind
                    $.ajax({ // here i have called a method in aspx.cs
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "sick.aspx.cs/desease",
                        data: { date: $('#now').val() },
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
                    });


                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: While passing the slider value to "sick.aspx/desease",  It is not require to pass the .cs extension and also "desease" must be [webmethod]

Comment: could you please modify the answer ajax call

Comment: I could not get you answer means..